# MQTT on React Native: AMQJS0016E Invalid MQTT message type 0

Tags: reactjs, native, mqtt, paho

I am using Paho Mqtt JS (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript) on React Native via the bridge (https://github.com/Introvertuous/react_native_mqtt)

It works well on the old version of React Native

```
"react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
"react-native": "0.40.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.9.2",
"react-native-storage": "^0.1.4",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
"react_native_mqtt": "^1.1.4"
```

But it doesn't work any more with new versions:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.46.4",
"react-native-elements": "^0.15.0",
"react-native-storage": "^0.2.2",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
"react_native_mqtt": "^1.1.6"
```

I always get the error "`Object {invocationContext: undefined, errorCode: 16, errorMessage: "AMQJS0016E Invalid MQTT message type 0."}`"

I think there are changes in the new version of RN may break the mqtt feature (may be related to websocket ?)

I tried a lot of ways but can not find any clue to solve the issue. Please help me... any idea is welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

This is/was due to a React Native bug.

Binary WebSockets in react native on android were broken by commit [93a1d5](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/93a1d592d61b229d3dafe57d1590d286312cc0bf) (which first landed in the 0.46 release) and later fixed by [7e29b1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7e29b1fc7711a285765f021be3e83a981b066435) (which will land in 0.48 but was also [cherry-picked](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/048a5fd57cc47b7db0d14cc2267fe482fcba24d9) into 0.47 final).

So, you should find that updating React Native to 0.47.* fixes the issue for you. If you need to monkey-patch 0.46 instead, just apply the one-liner [7e29b1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7e29b1fc7711a285765f021be3e83a981b066435). HTH.